# 18.04 - does it force netplan or can I still use resolved.conf?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dns, netplan

I kept getting timeout errors on 18.04 Bionic Beaver, until I switched to OpenDNS using these commands

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
# with body 
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Should I really be doing this OpenDNS configuration with Netplan? I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
# Create a netplan file
sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

.

```
# Put this in the body
nameservers: 
    addresses: [208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]
```

I also tried this syntax in the body to no avail, but maybe it because I'm on wifi and I called out 'ethernet'??? wlo1 is my wifi logical name when I `sudo lshw -C network`.

```
network:
  ethernet:
    wlo1:
      nameservers:
        addresses: [208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220]
```

Comment: You first have to make a decision to use NetworkManager or netplan. If you connect wi-fi to various wireless networks, then NetworkManager is probably the better choice. Netplan is best used in servers, where the configuration doesn't change much. See https://netplan.io/examples.

Comment: @heynnema is this NetworkManager? Or is it something else? Please see this image https://linuxconfig.org/images/06-set-configure-static-ip-address-ubuntu-18.04-bionic-linux.png

Comment: That's NetworkManager. netplan has no GUI... only files in /etc/netplan, and the netplan CLI. However, if you're using NetworkManager, there's still one relevant .yaml file in /etc/netplan.

Comment: @heynnema and correct me if I'm wrong but I'll need to enable NetworkManager for 18.04 in my `/etc/netplan` file like this: `network:\n [TAB]version: 2 [TAB]renderer: NetworkManager` and then I run `netplan generate && netplan apply`.

Comment: That's correct. Indentation is important. See my answer, below, or the examples site that I quoted earlier. Use spaces, not tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first have to make a decision to use NetworkManager or systemd-networkd. If you connect wi-fi to various wireless networks, then NetworkManager is probably the better choice. systemd-networkd is best used in servers, where the configuration doesn't change much. See https://netplan.io/examples.

/etc/netplan .yaml example to enable NetworkManager...

---

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

---

In `terminal`...

`sudo netplan generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply the new config

`reboot` # reboot to confirm network operation

Comment: Probably you meant "You first have to make a decision to use NetworkManager or *systemd-networkd*." The configuration in your answer is using netplan, with NetworkManager as the renderer (instead of systemd-networkd).

Comment: THANK YOU. I used the mini ISO to install Ubuntu, and connected via WiFi during the install process. When I installed my GUI desktop I found that network manager didn't pick up my WiFi! (I use Ansible to provision my desktops to prefer to start with a blank slate, hence mini ISO). This helped me, thank you.

Comment: @AsfandQazi Glad it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is *systemd-networkd.service*, instead of *NetworkManager.service*.

**Background story**

I was having problems with NetworkManager when after changing network settings a couple of times the DNS  would fail.

I noticed that `systemd-resolved.service` is supposed to work with both `network-manager` and `systemd-network`.

But `systemd-networkd` is actually part of the `systemd` family of software.  So (I thought maybe) it will communicate better with `systemd-networkd` than `NetworkManager`.  It tried it and it did seem better.

**How to set up `systemd-networkd`**

Set up `/etc/systemd/network/10-enp2s0.network` where `enp2s0` is the name of your interface as seen with `ifconfig`.  It might be `eth0`.  Here is a simple example of DHCP with DNS override.  Note the `DNS=` directive can be used multiple times.

```
[Match]
MACAddress=1c:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd

[Network]
DHCP=yes
DNS=208.67.222.222
DNS=208.67.220.220
```

The `[Network]` section for a fixed address.

```
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.172/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=208.67.222.222
DNS=208.67.220.220
```

[More examples](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Examples)

Test it out -

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl start systemd-networkd.service
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

On my system with `systemd-resolved` running, the `resolv.conf` file is a link -

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

If the link is not replaced automatically during the `restart`, you might want to link it manually and restart `systemd-resolved` again.

If its working as hoped than set their boot time startup behaviour -

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
```

**Blame**

There are always two sides to an interface.