# How to prevent kernel upgrade from changing systemd configuration

Tags: upgrade, kernel, configuration

I recently upgraded the Ubuntu kernel from 4.18.0-15 to 4.18.0-18.
As a result, it silently overrode my

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

setting, and enabled it again.  (I am using only `systemd-networkd`.)

Is there a way to prevent this configuration change on kernel update?
If not, why not?

Comment: Are you on a desktop machine, or a server? Why would you disable NM? Are you running netword (netplan)? Show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: I'm not using netplan (the config files is the default nearly empty) just the config files `/etc/systemd/network/*` and `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.  The reasons for that is explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1114904/723997 .  Basically, I found that `systemd-networkd` alone works better with `systemd-resolved`.  Specifically changing system settings caused DNS to fail when `NetworkManager` was involved.  By the way, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` invoked `NetworkManager.service`.  Once I disabled the former, the latter wasn't activated at boot.  It could be that such behavior is not new - I never noticed `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` before and usually boot up with the online connection present.

Since the question is "wrong", I am open to removing it.  On the other hand it might helpful to leave it.

Comment: It's a legitimate question, and your answer says *why* it happened. I see no reason to remove it :) You should consider accepting your answer if noone else answers :)

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow when it is allowed (2 days) barring a better answer.  
I appreciate the advice.